# What do the symbols mean in minimap2's gap cost equation?

Tags: sequence-alignment, read-mapping, minimap2

Heng Li's [paper on minimap2](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/34/18/3094/4994778) is understandable to me right up until the moment that it gives this definition of gap cost:

> #### 2.2.1 Alignment with 2-piece affine gap cost
>
> Minimap2 performs DP-based global alignment between adjacent anchors in a chain. It uses a 2-piece affine gap cost [(Gotoh, 1990)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02458577):
>
> $$\gamma_a(l) = \min \{ q + |l| \cdot e, \tilde{q} + |l| \cdot \tilde{e} \}$$

Suddenly, out of nowhere, we've got *five* variables used without prior introduction: $l$, $q$, $e$, $\tilde{q}$, and $\tilde{e}$.

Heng doesn't state their meanings, and based on a quick skim and text search of the cited paper by Gotoh, that paper doesn't use these variable names anywhere either.

What does this equation mean?

Answer (score 5):

Here is the translation:

- $l$ = gap length
- $q$ = initial gap penalty for *shorter* gaps
- $e$ = *short* gap extension penalty per every additional gap
- $\tilde{q}$ = initial gap penalty for *longer* gaps
- $\tilde{e}$ = *long* gap extension penalty per every additional gap

To understand the first of the two expressions being minimized, see the Wikipedia section on [affine gap penalties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gap_penalty#Affine).

Notice the similar notation structure

$$A + B \cdot L$$

where

- $A$ is the known gap penalty,
- $B$ is the gap extension penalty, and
- $L$ is the length of the gap

To understand the other variables with the tildes on top, see the text below Equation 2 (emphasis added to key explanation):

> On the condition that $e > \tilde{e}$⁠,
>   it applies cost
>   $q + |l| \cdot e$
>   to gaps shorter than
>   $[(\tilde{q} - q)/(e - \tilde{e})]$
>   and applies
>   $\tilde{q} + |l| \cdot \tilde{e}$
>   to longer gaps. **This scheme helps to recover longer insertions and deletions (INDELs)**.

In other words, we make the assertion that we should penalize longer gaps differently than shorter gaps.

As a bonus, here's a visual understanding of why we use the minimization function on those two expressions using Python and some made-up (and probably not biologically useful) penalty terms. **Note** the requirement that $e > \tilde{e}$.

```py
# Import libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Setup
l = np.array(range(0, 15, 1))  
y_short = eval('10 + 5*l') # Q=10, E=5
y_long = eval('20 + 3*l')  # Q=20, E=3

# Plot
plt.plot(l, y_short)
plt.plot(l, y_long)
plt.legend(["Short Gap Penalty", "Long Gap Penalty"])
```

[image: Plot example expressions for long and short gap penalty expressions]

Using our example and the expression $[(\tilde{q} - q)/(e - \tilde{e})]$, it will apply the first expression in the minimization function (the one without the tildes) when the gap length is shorter than 5.

$$
[(\tilde{q} - q)/(e - \tilde{e})]
=
[20 - 10)/(5 - 3)]
=
10 / 2
= 5
$$

We can see from our plot that the two lines intersect at 5, which we've verified through some arithmetic.